# Gulp looping a watch task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-uglify

I'm new in Gulp and this is my code that just minifies my JS script:

```
gulp.task('minify-js', function(){
    return gulp.src(['assets/js/**/*.js', '!assets/js/**/*.min.js'])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
});
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    //gulp.watch(['sass/**/*.sass'], gulp.series('css-files'));
    gulp.watch(['assets/js/**/*.js'], gulp.series('minify-js'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('watch'));
```

When I run `gulp default` and edit any `JS` file, my task starts looping for no reason and the files keep being minified and merged aswell. Why? It should stop after one execution!

example:
[image]

*This code runs perfectly without the watch task

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Your destination file matches the mask of source files.

So Gulp process the file it just generated themself. And then again, and again.

**Update**: you've excluded the file in `minify-js` task, but not excluded in `watch` task. Set `watch` argument the same as for `minify-js` and that should help.